# How to alter Spring Bean initialization order?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have an annotation-configured Spring web app, I need to alter bean creation order to define what is the very first bean loaded during context boot up.
Is it possible without switching to xml configuration?

Comment: See [Spring: Make sure a particular bean gets initialized first](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7868335/5221149).

Comment: you can check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31692905/spring-boot-auto-configuration-order)

Comment: You say you have to but don't say why. There are ways to do this, but you shouldn't have to. Please post a relevant sample of your configuration and indicate which beans have to be created first.

Comment: If no database is ready i have to set it up, therefore I have to be sure that the database service should start for first because many other services need the database.