# Manipulate the order of library's auto-configuration class

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have created a so-called "starter" library. My question is: how can I decide the order of its execution in other Spring Boot application?

Suppose this library has an auto-configuration class `FooAutoConfiguration`. Suppose, I'm using this library in some other Spring Boot application, and I want `FooAutoConfiguration` to be autowired before `BarBean`.

The key is that I would like, if possible, to achieve that in the library, not the Spring Boot application. Actually, I do not care if the `FooAutoConfiguration` is launched as fast as possible, as it does not depend on nothing but a configuration properties class.

Comment: Would [@DependsOn](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/DependsOn.html) work for you?

Comment: Have you checked: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27667516/7326551